# Нужно ли ставить точку или двоеточие после слова "Инструкция" или "Аннотация"?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

Речь о ситуации, когда после слова  "Инструкция" или "Аннотация" идет абзац из нескольких предложений, а сам текст не начинается с него (т.е. это не заголовок). Что должно быть здесь - точка, двоеточие или отсутствие знака?

> *Новинка в нашей книжной лавке!*
>
> *"Красная шапочка". Автор: Шарль Перро.*
>
> ***Аннотация.***
>
> *Пирожки и горшочек масла. Вот и вся компания юной мадемуазели на пути через дикий лес, в котором обитает злодейский злобный серый волк.
> Кажется, он тоже знает толк в пирожках. Чем же закончится эта
> история?*

.

> *Как смазать Железного Дровосека?*
>
> *Ниже мы подробно рассмотрим испытанный веками способ.*
>
> ***Инструкция.***
>
> *Раздобудьте небольшую масленку. 250-300 мл будет достаточно. Капните 2-3 капли на шарнирное соединение, подождите 10 секунд и попробуйте
> повернуть его. Повторите, если добиться результата не удалось.
> Продолжайте, пока Железный Дровосек не будет полностью подвижен.*

Логика подсказывает, что правильный ответ - "точка", но правил на эту тему мне найти не удалось. Правила постановки двоеточия вроде бы [никак не касаются](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/157-dvoe) подобной ситуации, а не ставить никакой знак могло бы быть логичным, если рассматривать слово как еще один заголовок внутри текста. Что верно?

Answer (score 2):

Мне логика подсказывает, что одиночные слова "Аннотация" и "Инструкция" **в таком** оформлении все-таки являются заголовками и **в конечной точке не нуждаются**.
Такие заголовки называются тематическими (то есть словесно определяющими тему структурной части текста).

Издательский словарь-справочник:
[заголовок](https://publishing_dictionary.academic.ru/193/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA) — название внутреннего подраздела произведения (главы, параграфа, части, раздела) или издания (раздела, части, элементов аппарата); название структурной части рубрики вспомогательного указателя, обозначающей объект поиска...

> **7.** В конце заголовков точка не ставится, независимо от их структуры (односоставное номинативное предложение, двусоставное и т. д.)...

[Знаки препинания в газетных и журнальных заголовках](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=168#pp168)
[Правильная аннотация к научной статье](https://sibac.info/blog/pravilnaya-annotaciya-k-nauchnoy-state)